# Creating a text input like the Web Telegram

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, css

I have a small chat functionality in my web application. At the moment the text input is a standard `textarea`. What I want is something similar to Telegram. They start of with a single line input element. If the User then types and hits enter the input grows in height until a certain point.

Is this possible with html and css?

```
<form asp-controller="Conversation" asp-action="SendMessage">
    <input hidden id="ConversationId" name="ConversationId" value="@Model.Id" />
    <div class="input-group">
        <textarea id="Body" name="Body" rows="1" class="form-control" 
         autocomplete="off"></textarea>
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Edit:
I know it works with a `div` and `contentEditable` but then the problem is that the content will not be submitted because a `div` is not a form element.

Comment: Why won't it work?

Comment: @fuzz because i am submitting a form when the user sends the message. And the div content is not part added as a value to the form data. Is there a possibility I can add it as form data?

Comment: Provide some code and we might be able to help.

Comment: @fuzz The issue is not ASP.NET Core, the issue is that a `div` is not a `form element` so it will not be serialized as `form data`. I edited my original question and provided some code.

Answer (score 1):

Create a div and style it with **-webkit-appearance** and **-moz-appearance** and set **contenteditable** attribute

- Also create hidden input element
- With javascript add div element text to hidden element
- Then you can use it in form for submiting

> The hidden input will be serialized as a form data, however **css appearance property** is not supported in IE 6-10 and 11.

**Run snippet and test it:**

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input"),
   button = document.getElementById("send-button"),
   message = document.getElementById("message");
   
   
   
input.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
 const target = e.target;
 
 var value = target.textContent || target.innerText;
    
 //Escape any space before and after input
 value = value.replace(/(\s+)/g, '');
    
 //Set the value to message input
 message.value = value;   
}) 



//Send the message input
button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 //assume your sending the input to server
 // if the value is not empty
 if(message.value !== '') {
  alert(message.value)
 }
 
});
```

```css
#input {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    background-color: -moz-field;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    /* font: -moz-field;
    font: -webkit-small-control; */
  font-size: .9rem;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: .8rem .5rem;
    width: 200px;  
  
}
```

```html
<div id="input" contenteditable data-placeholder="Enter your text"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="message"/>

<button type="submit" id="send-button">
Send
</button>
```

[Live example in JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Talavoock/4vedynqz/19/)